# Getting data from online database Android?

Tags: android

I'm Creating app that gets data from database, after user install the app , I'll update my database with new data every week , How can I let my database update automatically every time new items added and replace it with exiting one , without needing to update the whole app ?

Comment: well, u need to to write a code in php or .net etc. to handle the database functionality which acts as mediator between android and database server so that you need not have to change the whole app.

Comment: **Webservice** is the way to go with.

Comment: web service is the best way to do it

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code sample how to populate local db:

```
    public CreatePopulateDB(SQLiteDatabase database){
        database.execSQL("BEGIN TRANSACTION");  

        database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS xyz;");
        database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE xyz( field1 integer primary key autoincrement, field2 numeric not null, );");
        database.execSQL("INSERT INTO xyz VALUES(1,1);"); 
        database.execSQL("INSERT INTO xyz VALUES(2,2);"); 
...
        database.execSQL("COMMIT;");
    }
```

As stated in comment above, you'd populate the local db with data from php API.

Answer (score 0):

this is how you can retrieve data from your web service

```
public class GetXMLTask
{
        public static final String URL = "http://localhost:8080/appName/actionOrServletTobeCalled";
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        GetXMLTask obj = new GetXMLTask();
        String username = "username";
        String password = "password";
        obj.getOutputFromUrl(URL+"?"+username+"&password="+password);

    }
    public String getOutputFromUrl(String url) 
    {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpResponse response;
        StringBuilder builder= new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new                            InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
        char[] buf = new char[8000];
        int l = 0;
            while (l >= 0) 
            {
                builder.append(buf, 0, l);
                l = in.read(buf);
            }
        return builder.toString();
    }   
}
```

let me know if you need any help with the web service creation

Comment: thanks, and yes please tell me more about web services and how can I download my database to location data/database to start retrive data from it ?!!

Comment: I think its better download just data you wanted and update your db with that other than download the whole db each time ...